# Programming NRF52840 dongle from PlatformIO

Tags: platformio, nrf52

I am following https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/nordicnrf52/nrf52840_dk.html but I don't actually have a DK, I have an NRF52840 "Dongle".  Does anybody know if it's possible for that to work directly with PlatformIO?  It has a built in bootloader, but I don't think it emulates the right kind of programmer.  I have nrfutil installed but that wants a package (.zip) and platformio is producing .elf/.hex ... not sure how to connect these tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nrfutil pkg generate` to convert the hex files into a package:

https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/ug_nrfutil/UG/nrfutil/nrfutil_pkg.html

FYI, you might not get much benefit from using PlatformIO since you don't have a debugging interface. Depending on the framework you're using, there might be other options, like this documentation for Zephyr:

https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/boards/arm/nrf52840dongle_nrf52840/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`platformio.ini` configuration:

```
[env:nrf52840_dongle]
platform = nordicnrf52
board = nrf52840_dk
framework = zephyr
board_build.zephyr.variant = nrf52840dongle_nrf52840
extra_scripts = dfu_upload.py
upload_protocol = custom
```

add to project root `dfu_upload.py` script:

```
import sys
import os
from os.path import basename
Import("env")

platform = env.PioPlatform()

def dfu_upload(source, target, env):
    firmware_path = str(source[0])
    firmware_name = basename(firmware_path)


    genpkg = "".join(["nrfutil pkg generate --hw-version 52 --sd-req=0x00 --application ", firmware_path, " --application-version 1 firmware.zip"])
    dfupkg = "nrfutil dfu serial -pkg firmware.zip -p COM14 -b 115200"
    print( genpkg )
    os.system( genpkg )
    os.system( dfupkg )

    print("Uploading done.")


# Custom upload command and program name
env.Replace(PROGNAME="firmware", UPLOADCMD=dfu_upload)
```

- add [nrfutil](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/pc-nrfutil/releases) location to your system configuration "path" variable
- before upload firmware switch dongle to dfu mode (button reset)
- setup dongle COM number in line: `dfupkg = "nrfutil dfu serial -pkg firmware.zip -p COM14 -b 115200"` in dfu_upload.py

lots of examples you can find here: [Zephyr github](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/tree/master/samples)